# Moving Activity to another Activity when class extends ArrayAdapter

Tags: android

When I click the `edit_remainder` button I want to move my Activity to another Activity.

But where the class extends ArrayAdapter I don't understand how to move to another Activity.

Please help me with an example of the Intent class.

```
public class mylist extends ArrayAdapter<String> implements OnClickListener 
{

  private final Context context;
  private final String[] values;
  Button edit_remainder;

  public mylist(Context context, String[] values) {
    super(context, R.layout.some, values);
    this.context = context;
    this.values = values;
  }

  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.buttonadd, parent, false);
    edit_remeinder=(Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.btnEdit);
    edit_remeinder.setOnClickListener(this);
    return rowView;
  }

  public void onClick(View v) {
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "hi", 1000).show();
    // please enter moving code here
  }
}
```

Comment: Is this the actual code? If so you have a discrepancy `edit_remainder`  vs. `edit_remeinder`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you wish to transfer control to another activity when the user taps on a list item. You will need to issue an **intent**.

Here's a tutorial: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidIntent/article.html

Comment: Sir,The Class is extending ArrayAdapter so there is an error on the Intent. Yes i want to transfer control to another activity when user click on the Edit_remeinder  button. please help me ..

Answer (score 0):

launch an explicit intent here like:

```
Intent i=new Intent(context,anotheractivity.class);
startActivity(i);
```

here the context could be the application context.

Comment: the class is extends ArrayAdapter so if i am using Intent it shows an error.

Answer (score 0):

Are you create your own adapter(mylist)?
If yes then pass the intent in your main class from you call the mylist adapter.

Comment: yes i am creating my own adapter. But i didnt understood the way you said can you explain me with an example? please

Comment: Please check, I give another answer,May be it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

here I created for listview ,but you can try for your own application.
pass the intent in your main activity instead of your own adapter.

mainActivity.java

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
    setContentView(R.layout.main);  

    lview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView2);  
    lviewAdapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, month, number);  //here ListViewAdapter is my own adapter

    System.out.println("adapter => "+lviewAdapter.getCount());  

    lview.setAdapter(lviewAdapter);  

    lview.setOnItemClickListener(this);  
}  

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long id) {  
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    Toast.makeText(this,"Title => "+month[position]+"=> n Description"+number[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  

     // here your intent code

}  
}
```

please put this onclick method in your main activity and try again.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
Toast.makeText(getContext(), "hi", 1000).show();
// please enter moving code here

}
```